# nameof in attribute

Tags: c#, nameof, .net-attributes

Considering `Myatt` attribute and `MyObj` class, it is somehow strange that `ObjName` property is known in scope of `Myatt` attribute. Isn't it?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyAtt : Attribute
{
    public MyAtt(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class MyObj
{
    [MyAtt(nameof(ObjName))] //Can access to ObjName?!
    public int ObjID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ObjName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Update :

Sorry, I'm wondering why the first case is not possible and the second is possible.

```
1. [MyAtt(nameof(this.ObjName))] 
2. [MyAtt(nameof(ObjName))]
```

I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question? If we also find it strange that your code works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's good that it's supported there, isn't it? So no, it's not strange.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) mentions an `Attribute` example as key use case:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("={" + nameof(GetString) + "()}")]  
class C {  
    string GetString() { }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider `nameof(...)` as syntactic sugar, then it's not strange - your attribute takes a string, and the compiler works out that string at compile time (taking into account any renames as a result of refactoring)